# is there a way to trigger reload in react native

Tags: react-native

please i am trying to trigger a reload in my app after the NativeModules.NotifcationModule runs. Here is my code.
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
}

```
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    console.log("before modules")
    NativeModules.NotificationModule.triggerFullScreenNotification(remoteMessage.notification.title, remoteMessage.notification.body, 'limestone');
    console.log('Android Message handled in the background');
    console.log(remoteMessage);
    //reload application here
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure react native has a direct equivalent to triggering a full reload from within the application itself. I could be wrong ‍♂️

However, you should be able to use the AppState API to detect changes in the app state (e.g., from background to active) and trigger actions accordingly. You can use a workaround  like this:

```js
import { AppState, Platform, NativeModules, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

// Add an AppState listener
const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (nextAppState === 'active') {
    // Reload the application
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      console.log('Reloading the application...');
      NativeModules.DevSettings.reload(); // This will trigger a reload
    }
  }
};

// Attach the listener when the component mounts
useEffect(() => {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
  
  // Clean up the listener when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
  };
}, []);

// ...

// Inside your existing implementation
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  console.log("before modules")
  NativeModules.NotificationModule.triggerFullScreenNotification(remoteMessage.notification.title, remoteMessage.notification.body, 'limestone');
  console.log('Android Message handled in the background');
  console.log(remoteMessage);
}
```

Comment: it did not work. document not defined

Comment: @OtonyeAmietubodie Apologies, I completely forgot it was react native and not web, I'll update my response.

Comment: thanks bro, this works. but when the app reloads it enters an infinite loop and keeps reloading